# Drawing, using actual pixels, on retina display

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, coordinates, retina-display

What I need to do to draw some shapes on retina display, defining actual screen pixels.
I mean that I need that all lines will be 1 pixel width, and no antialiasing. And, if i write the the code:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context,0,0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,0,959);
```

then on display will be line from the upper left most pixel toward lowest left most pixel including it.

If I understood well, I need to use CGContextScaleCTM. But there is not always the same regularity in coordinates.
Sometimes there is offset on Y-axis, and sometimes no. I have tried to write some macro for converting the coordinates, but have confused at all.
I know, that there is logical points and auto positioning stuff. But that is the point that I need to draw all the pixels manually, cause I'm developing some
util.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.5, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.5, 959);
```

**Why:** A 1.0 pixel wide line will be centered on the coordinates you give it.  So if you start at (0, 0), half of the line will be in the column from -1 to 0, and half of the line will be in the column from 0 to 1.  Integer coordinates give you the corners of the pixels, which is good for things like raster images.

Comment: There is stil the problem in some functions like:

    CGContextAddRect(...)

I'm using many different CG functions and many loops in my app. Is there some way to map to pixels and not to edge of pixels?

Comment: The code I give above maps to pixels and not to edges of pixels.